# Diagnosing the cause of frequent reboots

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, reboot

I am trying to diagnose the cause of frequent restarts on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine. [Given my past experiences](https://askubuntu.com/questions/788855/qualcomm-atheros-ar93xx-wireless-network-adapter-ubuntu-16-04-woes), I am strongly inclined to believe that this is a hardware problem rather than a software problem.

I will provide details of everything I have tried below, but I would like to understand:

- How can I figure out whether this is a hardware problem or a software problem?
- How can I isolate the what is causing the issue in either one of the scenarios above?

I can provide any additional hardware or log details that might be required to diagnose this.

---

So far, I have focussed on understanding whether it is an Ubuntu problem, and I have:

- Start by looking at the output of `last reboot`. Was not able to make sense of the output, so have posted a question about it [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/817430/understanding-the-output-of-last-reboot).
- Checked the solutions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202335/how-can-i-track-the-cause-of-random-reboots).

  - Checked whether the kernel panic value is set to 1, so that on panic the system will immediately reboot: `tail /proc/sys/kernel/panic` gave a value of 0.
  - The answers also suggest looking at the unattended upgrades file, and seeing if the automatic reboots are set to true. Have explicitly set  `Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot` to `false`.
  - Also checked that there were no upgrades around the time that the two reboots occurred.
- Another set of suggestions around this problem is here : http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/ubuntu-14-04-suddenly-reboots-4175547146/.

  - These guys suggest that this could be a set of bad capacitors.
  - Incompatible memory? Memory settings?
- The next set of suggestions is here: [Ubuntu restarts randomly](https://superuser.com/questions/286691/ubuntu-restarts-randomly). Says that this might be related to the screensaver. Not sure how to fix this.

Comment: To determine whether it is a hardware problem, you should boot an OS from USB and work in it until reboot happens. If reboot happens, then it is a hardware problem. If you find nothing suspicious in the logs, then it also points at hardware cause.

Comment: @Alexiy That is an excellent suggestion -- thanks.